# Next to no glute / hamstring activation when squatting

Tags: squats, muscle-imbalance, hamstring, glutes

What to do?

Even when squatting without weight, I just  feel like the quads are doing 99.8% of the work. Lately I've been having some discomfort while squatting with higher weights. Is there a way to   target specifically those muscles?

Comment: Are you squatting high bar or low bar?  Low bar will have a lot more glute/ham activation.

Comment: Not many people are native English speakers including me. Can you please indicate which muscles are 'those muscles'? Quads or glutes & hamstring?

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you can do, just know that in a raw squat (no squat suit or compression briefs) the glute involvement is primarily at the bottom, and [the hamstrings are only moderately used](http://gregnuckols.com/2014/01/23/hamstrings-the-most-overrated-muscle-group-for-the-squat/).  With a squat suit, the leverages change and loading the hamstrings is more important.  That said, the glute and hamstring activity is still important--particularly for deadlifts.

**Hamstring Exercises**

- [Exercise ball leg curls](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/ball-leg-curl)
- [Romanian Deadlifts](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/romanian-deadlift)
- [Good Mornings](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/good-morning)
- [Glute-Ham Raise](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/glute-ham-raise)

**Glute Exercises**

- [Glute Bridges](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/barbell-glute-bridge)
- [Barbell Hip Thrust](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/barbell-hip-thrust)
- [Single Leg Glute Bridge](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/single-leg-glute-bridge-)

Also, I recommend doing deadlifts if you don't already.  It is the ultimate posterior chain movement.